# SSRS Line Chart not pulling through Feb data - potential unknown exclusion

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder3.0, custom-formatting

I'm a little confused with this one. I have a dataset that I have connected to and checked and it holds Feb data however my line chart is only showing to January.

I have some custom formatting which I'm not sure is the problem. Listed below is the format's attached to the chart:

**Chart**

**Category Groups:**
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Val(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(Fields!year_month.Value, 6, 2)) & "/" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(Fields!year_month.Value, 3, 2)

**Chart areas**
**Catergory Axes**: All auto options

**Value Axes**: Label Format:
   =Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(System.Math.CEILING(Max(System.Math.Abs(Fields!avg_sentence_sentiment.Value)))
   = 1, "0.0;-0.0;0", "0.0;-0.0;0")

**Max:** 
   =System.Math.CEILING(Max(System.Math.Abs(Fields!avg_sentence_sentiment.Value)))

**Min:**
   =- System.Math.CEILING(Max(System.Math.Abs(Fields!avg_sentence_sentiment.Value)))

I'm sure I've created an exclusion somehow but I can't see and this has stumped me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I would just comment but I don't have the rep. :(

What is the expression for the **Value** of your chart?

Is it possible that there may be null values for the current month? You might need to account for them in your expression.

> =Sum(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!COUNT.Value), 0, Fields!COUNT.Value))

Does February show up on your chart axis or does the month not even appear?

Comment: Hi just checked and there are no null values within the data. Feb does not show up in the chart axis either. Double checked my data source and feb data is in there?

Comment: Hmm. It's a little harder. To start troubleshooting, you might want to make a copy of the report so you don't butcher your original. 
Start by removing any Filters that are on the chart.

You can also add a table with the data from the chart and look for the Feb data to make sure that it is coming through the dataset.
Also try removing things like your Axis Min and Max expressions and anything else until you get it working.